# In Windows 7 Where is the touch cursor stored?

Tags: windows-7, touchscreen

In windows 7 on a touch screen pc, there is a small white cursor that appears when you touch the screen.

I would like to remove/customise this icon. Where can I find it?

Here is an image of the icon:
[image]

Comment: Could you plz make a screenshot and show how does it looks like

Comment: I added an image for you

Comment: This might be related: https://superuser.com/questions/623183/how-do-i-disable-the-small-pen-cursor-in-windows-7?rq=1

Comment: I found these registry settings that may be related: http://superuser.com/a/933751/230910  - I wonder if it is possible to set the "delay before hiding" to Zero

Comment: It goes easier than with the registry. Look at my answer below!

Comment: i tried that, but it doesnt work, the touch pointer there refers to a thing that looks like a mouse, not the white dot. The cursor editor only shows mouse cursors, so i cant edit the touch pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cursor is stored as a bitmap in C:\Windows\system32\user32.dll. [Further details here.](https://superuser.com/a/1550952/967287)

Answer (score 0):

The Different Cursors Are Stored In The Folder:
 `C:\Windows\System32\Cursors` On My Windows 7 PC.
I hope this helped.
The configuration could be different for your PC.

Comment: Thanks for this info, i had a good look through the files there, but it seems windows only puts the mouse cursors there, the touch pointers must be somewhere else..

Answer (score 0):

I have this cursor!!
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1upkIL9bmzNWVZUb_EjFomK_UzZnxbFDw/view?usp=sharing

These cursor were extracted from the dll "UIHub.dll"
located in C:\Windows\system32\UIHub.dll of windows 7, or you can try to search for downloading this dll.
I didn't find the location of these cursors in windows 10, you can search using the same method I used or work on top of those in windows 7 to try to improve the resolution.

I used the website http://www.win7dll.info which has dlls from several windows os. On this same page there are
"Top 10 DLL files with largest number of cursors" to which I entered each dll and looked for cursor preview and found in a dll as I mentioned.
soon after I downloaded the program

https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/iconsext.html
which is a website of programs that dll information provides.
in the program I just added the dll and easily extracts the cursors.

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE: This does not work either!!!

From this link: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/dynamic-pen-feedback-in-windows-7-cant-turn-off/7152da79-7c00-4af7-bb9a-c69f5dd3b3f8?page=5

I found the following:

> If you're willing to edit the registry manually you can use the following instructions to do the same:
>
> Open the Run dialog with the Windows Key + R shortcut
>       Type in "regedit" (without the quotes), press Enter and click Yes on the UAC dialog to open Registry Editor
>       Use the tree-view in the left panel of Registry Editor to navigate to the Computer > HKEY_CURRENT_USER > Software > Policies > Microsoft
>
> > TabletPC registry key. (If any of those keys don't exist, you might have to create them yourself through the Edit > New > Key menu item)
> >         In the right panel, look for a DWORD value named "TurnOffPenFeedback". If the value does not exist, create it yourself
> >     with the Edit > New > DWORD Value menu item (Make sure you've selected
> >     the TabletPC registry key first!).
> >         Set the TurnOffPenFeedback value to 1
> >         Close Registry Editor
> >         Open the Control Panel
> >         Go to the System and Security section and then to the Administrative Tools section.
> >         Open the Services console.
> >         Scroll the services list until you find a "Tablet PC Input Service" item.
> >         Right-click on that service and select Restart
> >         If you see a "TabletServicePen" item, restart that as well.