# Where to find/download Windows 10 Ink cursors/pointer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1703, mouse-cursor

While using a pen, Windows 10 (since the introduction of Windows Ink) has this nice special cursor [image]
and also respective animated versions of it for other states ("busy", etc.), it's just like the aero cursors but with this crosshair in place of the arrow.

Unfortunately, recent Wacom drivers makes the cursor to be the mouse cursor (e.g. whatever you set for mouse in Control Panel), i.e. the regular arrow, which is not cool when you're using a pen.
But because it now can be simply changed via Control Panel I thought to just set it to that Windows Ink crosshair cursor.

My problem is that I struggle to find it anywhere. Windows doesn't have it among *.cur files. Probably it's implemented in other way. Also google searche yields nothing, maybe I name it in a wrong way (windows ink/pen/stylus cursor/pointer).

While creating the cursor itself from a screenshot is trivial, creating other animated version of it is a bit more tricky.
So I was wondering if anyone can help with finding the cursor in Windows filesystem or somewhere else to download (if someone has made it or extracted from windows).

Edit:
A larger screenshot for better scale [image]

Comment: Could you provide a bigger screenshot? Does that cursor style appear in a specific program but not in other ones?

Comment: @Biswapriyo That cursor behaves like a default windows cursor whenever you use a pen on a display (e.g. a tablet or Wacom Cintiq/Companion/MobileStudio). It *is* windows-provided cursor. The screenshot is from an article about Windows Ink features. So anywhere there would be an arrow, there's this crosshair instead. At least it behaved so in older windows builds and/or with older drivers. It does not interfere with other programs, they can show their own cursors as usual with no issues (e.g. Photoshop).

Answer (score 0):

The cursor is stored as a 32x32 bitmap in C:\Windows\system32\user32.dll. To access it, you need to open the DLL file in Visual Studio (or something similar) and navigate to the bitmap under the 'Cursors' node.

I found out about this by looking at https://windows10dll.nirsoft.net/.

P.S. https://www.nirsoft.net/ is a great resource for finding out about obscure Windows features and settings. The software on the site has been useful to me hundreds of times when I tried to tweak something inside Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Have this [cursor](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1upkIL9bmzNWVZUb_EjFomK_UzZnxbFDw/view?usp=sharing)

These cursor were extracted from the dll "UIHub.dll" located in `C:\Windows\system32\UIHub.dll` of windows 7, or you can try to search for downloading this dll. I didn't find the location of these cursors in windows 10, you can search using the same method I used or work on top of those in windows 7 to try to improve the resolution.

I used the website http://www.win7dll.info which has dlls from several windows os. On this same page there are "Top 10 DLL files with largest number of cursors" to which I entered each dll and looked for cursor preview and found in a dll as I mentioned. soon after I downloaded the program

https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/iconsext.html which is a website of programs that dll information provides. in the program I just added the dll and easily extracts the cursors.

Answer (score 0):

I also had that problem and I also haven't found this pointer on the web, but I tried to create a pointer as similar as possible to the Windows Ink pointer, I hope it helps you:

https://www.mediafire.com/file/13hc1hmll0utoax/Cursor.cur/file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1124071)